# What is a Tao Buddhist?

Tags: belief, comparative-religion, taoism

This [answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3272/157) refers to a Tao Buddhist. I've never heard of this term. Is a a definite religious movement or is it just a colloquial term that refers to someone who holds both view simultaneously? In either case, is there any conflict when subscribing to both philosophies at the same time?

Comment: The earliest translations of Buddhist texts to Chinese just used Confucian and Taoist jargon in place of Buddhist jargon.  Syncretism happens.

Comment: I was wondering myself, because I know there are some trivial differences between the two.

Comment: There was a Neo-Confucianism movement back around 800 C.E.  It incorporated aspect of Taoism, Buddhism, and Confucianism.  Not sure if that's really what you're looking for though.

Comment: The statement "my mother was raised Tao Buddhist" is grammatically incorrect, it should say "Taoist and Buddhist". So "Tao Buddhist" is probably not a religious sect.

Source: my own experience growing up around Chinese speakers who learned English as a second language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think a Tao Buddhist is a Taoist an Buddhist. The Tao is the religious experience of the world, an the Buddhism is the philosophical experience of the world. The Tao developed its understanding of Yin an Yang this is sort like the Hindu/Buddhist concept of Karma.

You can find that Buddhism mingles with all type of religions. Buddhism is a very adaptable system that can help improve people in or out of religion.

Comment: "The Tao is the religious experience of the world, an the Buddhism is the philosophical experience of the world" is not really a concrete statement of fact. May I suggest replacing it with a fact, for example that Taoism and Mahayana Buddhism coexisted because Mahayana Buddhism was seen as external confirmation of Taoism.

Comment: Sure. The Question is What is a Tao Buddhist. A practitioner of Taoism and a Follower of Buddhism.Taoism is the religious aspect Because Taoism is a Form of religion, where forces of Yin an Yang Balance out the Universe an Buddhism would be the philosophical aspect Because it is commonly Known that Buddhism is not considered a religion. Well I guess I assumed they were asking what was the meaning of the term.Im glade that you came to add some help to the question, Now the user knows more about the connection of Taoism an Mahayana Buddhism that they didnt know before, thank you for helping.